# Inflict an injury on someone

Tags: legalese

> **AGGRIEVE**: to inflict an actionable injury on somebody
>
> Microsoft® Encarta® 2009

What does *inflict an injury* mean in this definition?

Comment: Nothing else than the normal meaning of "inflict" is involved in this definition; a dictionary will tell you that.

Comment: It means to harm the person.

Comment: @LPH **INJURY**: _the violation of a person's or group's rights, against which legal action can be taken_ 
Microsoft® Encarta® . So I don't know whether it is a physical injury.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a legal use of *aggrieve*. To *aggrieve* somebody is to anger and displease them with *injury* such as hurting their body, damaging their property or infringing their rights. If it is *actionable*, it means that the aggrieved person may try to get redress, compensation or justice by legal action.

[Legaldictionary](https://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Injury): Injury -
A comprehensive term for any wrong or harm done by one individual to another individual's body, rights, reputation, or property. Any interference with an individual's legally protected interest.